# Cocos2d-x with Visual Studio 2015 cross platform tools

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-2015

How do I set up Cocos2d-x (3.7) to work with Visual Studio 2015's new C++ cross platform tools for Android and iOS? This is relatively new, and there is not much documentation besides the simplest project. I have Cocos2d-x and a few SDKBOX plugins and I can't seem to get anything set up in Visual Studio.

Go vote here for a sample.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/requests/Cocos2d-x-e34be78c?ShowSubmitLinkForm=False

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/15/running-cocos2d-x-on-windows-10/) seems to hold an explanation and some examples (i.e. links to other git repos). I've followed the instructions below and was able to run a x86 executable on my development system (64 bit did not work). I did not check the Android or iOS projects.

I quoted the getting started part of the link, the rest of the page explains some details about the generated code.

> Getting Started
>
> Ensure you have Windows 10 installed. If you cannot install this on your primary machine, you can set up a virtual machine on Windows
>   10 for Cocos2d-x development.
>
> Download and install Microsoft Visual Studio. Make sure that the “Universal Windows App Development Tools” are selected from the
>   optional features list as these are needed for UWP development.Cocos
>   image 1
>
> Install Python 2.7.x
>
> Add c:\Python27 to the Path Environment setting

I think that I got a correct python installation with visual studio 2015 community edition, that is added to the path automatically.

> Clone the Cocos2d-x repo [https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x] and follow the steps described within the related readme file
>   (download-deps.py and git submodule update –init)

Instead of cloning the git repo, I actually downloaded cocos2d-x-3.8.1.zip from the website, so far this seems to work. I used the following commands in the folder where I unzipped.

```
python download-deps.py
python setup.py
```

As said I did not check the Android and/or iOS projects that were generated.

> Open up command prompt and use the command:
>
> ```
> cocos new myWin10Game -l cpp -d projects
> ```

NB: After this generation step, the output prompted me that I needed to change some things in the Android and iOS projects.

> Enter the proj.win10 folder and open the solution. In this example, it will be myWin10Game.sln.

Answer (score 0):

A Chinese guy made it. I have tried but has no idea how to add source code into VS 2015(Actually, he has mentioned "proj.win10" module???). Here the link:
http://blog.csdn.net/emcodelin/article/details/47956919

Here the section you may interesting (from google translate).

[image: Use Visual Studio 2015 debugger Android platform game Cocos2d-x C ++ code]

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old old, but if anyone hits it in search results there is now a Visual Studio project to target Android devices with Cocos2d-x. It's not integrated with the cocos template system, so it currently needs to be updated per cocos version. Currently it's for VS 2015 Update 3 and Cocos 3.12.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/12/cocos2d-x-visual-studio-android-project/

I developed it so feel free to ping any questions my way.

Answer (score -3):

Do you not still need at least access to a Mac with XCode?

Currently the entire project structure of Cocos2d-x is setup around having a Visual Studio solution for windows / windows phone builds, an xcode project for Mac and iOS builds and a NDK build script for Android builds.

So I would recommend concentrating on getting the supported builds working, and once you understand them, you can convert to an all-MSVC build process.

Comment: I currently have all the builds set up but I am constantly changing tools to build and debug. The new VS tools allow building Windows, Android, and iOS (Using a Mac build server) in one IDE. Getting the projects set up is where I'm having trouble.